# WebGL iOS Error: Assigning non-constant to 'const lowp 3-component vector of float'

Tags: ios, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL experiment that when finished, will hopefully be a playable synth:

https://mysterypancake.github.io/Waveform

The problem is, I'm rubbish at shaders. My shaders are in plain text here:

https://github.com/MysteryPancake/Waveform/blob/master/scripts/Shader.js

The problem lies with the droplet fragment shader:

```
void main(void) {
    lowp vec2 circCoord = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;
    if (dot(circCoord, circCoord) > 1.0) discard;
    const lowp vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(0, -1, -0.5));
    const lowp vec3 ambient = vec3(0.5, 0.2, 0.1);
    const lowp vec3 lightDiffuse = vec3(1, 0.5, 0.2);
    lowp vec3 normal = vec3(circCoord, sqrt(1.0 - dot(circCoord, circCoord)));
    lowp float color = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ambient + lightDiffuse * color, 1);
}
```

On iOS, this shader gives me this error:

> ERROR: 0:5: '=': assigning non-constant to 'const lowp 3-component
>   vector of float'

I can't quite figure out how to fix this. I can't even figure out if this is referring to line 7:

```
lowp vec3 normal = vec3(circCoord, sqrt(1.0 - dot(circCoord, circCoord)));
```

Or line 8:

```
lowp float color = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
```

Comment: for  reference see [glsl es 1.0 spec section 4.3.2](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf#page35). Question tho: did you not get this error on desktop?

Comment: @gman Not on desktop, and nice name

Comment: What browser on desktop? What OS on desktop? Which version of iOS on mobile? Which device? I am unable to repo on iOS 11 iPad Air 2 or iPhone 6+

Comment: Also does your iOS device [pass this test](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/misc/const-variable-initialization.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0)?

Comment: @gman Chrome and Safari don't give this error, at least on Mac. I have an outdated iPad 2 with iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: @gman I just opened the test, and there's a few fails every now and then. It is an ancient device though.

Comment: Ok, well, you Rabbid76 posted a workaround. I just wanted to point out it's against the spec but I'm guessing it was fixed and you just haven't updated your OS that includes the fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR: 0:5: '=': assigning non-constant to 'const lowp 3-component vector of float'.

This error message means, that you assign a non constant value to a variable declared `const`.

In your code, the error occurs in this line:

```
const lowp vec3 lightDir = normalize( vec3(0, -1, -0.5) );
```

In your case (this depends on the browser), the function `normalize` can not be transfomred to a constant expression.

Comment: This is a bug in some WebGL. A repo should be made and [it should be filed](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/new). The GLSL ES spec clearly says this is legal. Section 4.3 of the spec says you must use a constant expression. Section 5.10 defines constant expressions and they include built in functions except for texture lookup functions

Comment: Repeated from above but [the official test is here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/misc/const-variable-initialization.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0) and it appears to have been fixed on iOS sometime after iOS 9.3.5